# What is the use of consumer token services in spring boot oauth2?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I used JDBC token store in authorization server. But I don't know about the consumer token services. Can anyone explain it? How to revoke  the access token using consumer token services?

**Authorization Config**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSourceApi")
    DataSource dataSource;


    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ConsumerTokenServices defaultTokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }


     @Bean
    public JdbcClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsService() {
        return new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but this should have an answer for future devs.

When a user logs out, the access token should (must?!) be revoked. This can be done via

```
tokenServices.revokeToken(tokenId);
```

See eg. http://www.baeldung.com/logout-spring-security-oauth